# Polkadot.js API how to add the name of an item and collection of NFT's using uniques

Tags: polkadot-js, api, nft, uniques

could someone help me with this please.
I am using the polkadot.js explorer to add a collection of NFT's to a chain. I can add the collection using this.
[image]

Does anyone know how to add the name of an Item? So it will show up here.
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

`name` comes from ipfs JSON object that you can add using setMetadata call.

Let's say you have an object like

```
{
 name: 'My NFT #1',
 description: 'My first NFT on pallet uniques',
}
```

You then pin this object to ipfs first, then you get back ipfs CID, that you set as metadata on your uniques NFT using setMetadata

https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/blob/master/packages/page-nfts/src/Overview/Collection.tsx#L21

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. It's a bit late here now but I will try it tomorrow. Much appreciated mate.